# Using 3 Primary keys as one Foreign Key

Tags: sql

I need to send data from 3 different tables to one table.
Lets say T1, T2, T3 are sending ID to Employee. Here ID is Primary Key in T1, T2, T3 pointing ID as Foreign Key in Employee.

When I do this it gives error of "Foreign Key conflict in T2" when insertion from T1, T3 for T2 and T1 for T3.

There is one solution with me that I make separate Employee table for each T1, T2 and T3 but you know all of these table would carry same data so why not to put them in one table.  Is there any suggestions Please.

Comment: Include the schema. Something is clearly amiss with the usage (or perhaps definition) of such. (Also, this question as written, has *nothing* to do with VB or VS.)

Comment: If you have foreign key values from 3 tables (T1, T2, T3) stored in a single column of another table (T4), then you have probably missed out an 'entity type' from your data modelling.  You can't use that design and easily have the DBMS enforce your key constraints.  You'll need to tag which table (from T1, T2, T3) matches the ID value in each row in T4; that then contains the information you need. Writing enforcement code will be hell; don't do it.  Redesign the schema to avoid the need.

Comment: Let me  clear my question.  I am using three forms (Medical, Non Medical and Car) where data is different from each others, another form(Income) **has attributes like NIC etc**. attached to all of the forms. Now I want to use NIC as Foreign key From all (Medical, Non Medical and Car) forms in one table as INCOME.  In this case what should I do, If I'm not allowed to use any different key i-e NIC as Primary Key in Medical and Foreign Key in INCOME, ID as Primary Key in Non Medical and Foreign Key in INCOME and something else as Primary Key in Car and Foreign Key in INCOME. Thnx again.